# near-api-js: Contract connection with no sender account

Tags: smartcontracts, nearprotocol

Is there a way I can initially connect to a contract without a signer? I want like to create a user flow where the user can explore with view calls, then choose to connect their wallet at a later time.

Most examples I can find of Contract Connection code includes a wallet connected Account.
[docs](https://docs.near.org/docs/api/naj-quick-reference#load-contract)
[github docs](https://near.github.io/near-api-js/classes/contract.contract-1.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! You can query the state of an account by using the `providers` in `near-api-js`.

Example:

```js
const { providers } = require("near-api-js");
const provider = new providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://rpc.testnet.near.org");

getState();

async function getState() {
  const rawResult = await provider.query({
    request_type: "call_function",
    account_id: "guest-book.testnet",
    method_name: "getMessages",
    args_base64: "e30=",
    finality: "optimistic",
  });

  const res = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(rawResult.result).toString());
  console.log(res);
}
```

https://docs.near.org/docs/api/naj-cookbook#read-state-without-an-account

Comment: And how to pass args if I want to?

Comment: @kiskesis In the example above under the method name you'll see `args_base64`. This param requires a stringified object encoded in base64. If no args are needed simply pass `e30=` which is an empty object encoded in base64.